# Schedule followup reminder Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Many of my emails that I send out require a couple followups to get a response from people.  Often I just manually create calendar events to remind me to follow up with the person if they haven't responded.  Is there a way that outlook could create reminders for me when I write an email that I need to follow up with the person if I haven't received a reply in X amount of time?

I've seen a few plugins out there for outlook that automatically sends followups (not quite what I'm looking for but close).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may create a reminder when composing the message to remind yourself:

1. Go to Message tab, click Follow up > Add a reminder:
   [image]
2. Set a reminder for yourself:

   [image]